# Python: How to mock a value at import time?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to test a class (A) that extends another class (B). For my test I would like to mock class B to modify the behaviour of A but in order to do that I need to be able to apply the mock at import time. How would I do that? Please see below.

**database.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**models.py**

```
from .database import db

class Meta(db.Model):
    ...
```

In my unit test, I would like Meta to extend the standard python declarative Base so essentially I would like to mock database.py to instead act as if I'd done something like this:

```
db.Model = declarative_base()
```

My test currently looks like
**test_model.py**

```
from pkg.models import Meta

test_model()
    assert(...)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried patching `pkg.models.database` before doing the `from pkg.models import Meta` in your test?  (Not sure if that actually works, but it seems like if you want to patch the base class you need to apply the patch before the class definition executes, which means before you import the class.)